# Redirect to a directory, preserving the query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Any request for `/` that has a query string is causing a 404 to be triggered.  I've found that if I add a `/shop/` before the query string, it gets redirected internally and no 404 is triggered.

I need a general mod_rewrite rule that will take a URL in the form of:

```
http://www.example.com/?foo=bar
```

and redirect it to:

```
http://www.example.com/shop/?foo=bar
```

where the query string (could be anything) is preserved.

Comment: As I understand you want to have only 1 rewrite (not redirect) so when `/?foo=bar` is requested then it will actually be `/shop/?foo=bar` that gets executed (URL stays the same), right?

Comment: The homepage `/` for some reason returns a 404 when *any* query string is present, but `/shop/` works fine.  The rewrite or redirect should work for any number of query parameters and any parameter name, not just "foo".

Answer (score 0):

This will **redirect** (URL will change) all hits into ROOT (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`) that **has** query string into `http://www.example.com/shop/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/shop/ [QSA,R,L]
```

This will **rewrite** internally (URL will stay the same in browser) all hits into ROOT (e.g. `http://www.example.com/`) that **has** query string into `http://www.example.com/shop/`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^$ /shop/ [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the site is built on Miva Merchant and that /shop/ automatically redirects to / internally.  The addition of your RewriteRule causes an infinite redirection loop.  I need a rule that will ONLY apply to URLs with query strings, as the query string is stripped when it internally redirects to /.

Comment: @Jazzerus What other **"small minor nuances"** do you have? This already changes **everything** .. and without knowing how your existing redirect is done (Miva Merchant) everything that I can come up with will be just a "wild guess" at best. You have to look into your existing rewrite rules and find the reason why it does not work.

Comment: I guess maybe my question wasn't clear.  I needed a solution that ONLY works when there is a query string.  If a user goes to example.com without a query string, it should not redirect to example.com/shop.

Comment: @Jazzerus If root is hit and it has some query string, then it will 1) redirect or 2) rewrite into `/shop/` preserving the query string (you have to choose what is better suitable for you -- redirect or rewrite as many people confused about these terms).