# Redirect to a new website along with the query string parameters. DNS name only changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web, dns

If user types in this url

https://DNSName1/Work/Service?serviceId=11#tab_Foo

It should take them to

https://DNSName2/Work/Service?serviceId=11#tab_Foo

My website is deployed on IIS (8.5) Windows server 2012 machine. Also it is a MVC application

Looked into IIS http redirect and it seems like it doesn't preserve the query string.

Comment: Did you at least tried to search anything??? Just two hints: Request.Url and Response.Redirect.

Comment: quick search on stackoverflow could give you something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985068/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-url

Comment: @Gusman. Did search on both google and stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527156/redirect-to-a-directory-preserving-the-query-string. Had no correct marked answer here. http://www.wikihow.com/Redirect-a-URL

Comment: Request.Url.ToString() will give you the url including the query string, then Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString().Replace("oldDns", "newDns")) will redirect including the query string variables...

Comment: something like: `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("DNSName1", "DNSName2");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("DNSName1", "DNSName2"));
```

- `Response.Redirect` Redirects to new url.
- `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri` Gets you the current URL including query string
- `Replace("DNSName1", "DNSName2")` sets your new DNS name to the new one.